# Is there a limit to sending/ receiving from wallet to wallet?

Tags: wallet, sending

Seems like there is a restricted volume that a user can trade in the exchange, is there a similar restriction on transferring bitcoin from wallet A to wallet B? Say I want to send 100 Bitcoins to wallet B, would the transaction be denied due to its size?

Answer (score 2):

You're only limited by the amount of bitcoins under your control. There is effectively no limit on transferred value on the side of the protocol, as you would in fact be able to spend all bitcoins that will ever exist in a single transaction. (Hat-tip to Andrew Chow.) The biggest transaction in bitcoins I'm aware of were 550,000 BTC (then approx. $1,345,000), and the largest amount of value transferred in one transaction was $149,000,000 (~195,000 BTC) in a Bitstamp audit.

It may be that some exchanges limit the amount of bitcoins that you may withdraw in a single withdrawal. For further information on that, please refer to the respective user guide.

Comment: I see. Would it be the same case if i am using a hot wallet without exchange function?

Comment: Well there are limits actually. The amount you can spend is limited by the value field of the outputs, which is 8 bytes. That means there is a limit of 1.8446744*10^19 satoshis (or base units if that were to change). Of course that itself is limited by the money supply which has a theoretical maximum of 20999999.97690000 BTC. So the theoretical limit on a Bitcoin transaction is 20999999.97690000 BTC. But in practice, there really is no limit.

Comment: Right, thanks for the explanation. It would be interesting to put in scenario. Say I were to transfer 1 million BTC from wallet in country A to wallet in country B, given no restrictions, that would cause a massive capital outflow.

Comment: @cccc: Bitcoins are in no country and all countries at the same time. The distinction you're trying to make only comes into effect if you try to sell them for another currency as this sale will likely fall under some national jurisdiction.